# Problem understanding unusual syntax of the new keyword

Tags: c++

I stumbled across this piece of code, and could not understand how the `new` operator was used in this case:

```
student* setname(string name)
{
  student* stu=(student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
  new(stu) student;
  stu->age=12;
  stu->name=name;
  return  stu;
}
```

I would expect `new` to be used like `stu = new student;`. How is `new(stu) student` different?

Comment: See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Placement_new .

Comment: As Bob said, placement new - BUT *please never use code like this*! I don't speak Chinese (or should I say Mandarin?), so I can only read a translated version of the blog where this seems to come from - so maybe I'm missing something, but I don't understand why anyone teaching you C++ would recommend using malloc (which comes from C) and placement new instead of C++'s normal new operator. ALSO C++ functions should never return a raw pointer to freshly allocated memory (because someone *is* going to forget to delete it) --- AND why does a function called 'setname' *create a new student* anyway?